# Cause first div to overflow based on width of second div

Tags: html, css, less

I have two div elements sitting side by side. I want the left div to take remaining space of the width of the right div.

```css
.text {
  display: inline;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: red;
}

.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 92px;
  background-color: green;
}

.information {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="information">
  <div class="text">Text Here</div>
  <div class="icon">Image Here</div>
</div>
```

Everything I've tried, causes the icon div to resize/overflow based on the remaining space left from the text.

But I want my text div to overflow if the width on the icon div is more. Is there anyway to do this?

I can't set the width (using less or calc(totalWidth - iconWidth))
for the text div because the icon div's width can vary and I don't know what its value might be (the value of the icon's width is calculated in a mixin).

Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/fdur0wd1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `flex` on the parent, and set `.text` to `flex-grow: 1` (or `flex: 1 0 0` for short)

```css
.text {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: red;
    flex: 1 0 0;
}

.icon {
    width: 92px;
    background-color: green;
}

.information {
    width: 200px;
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="information">
    <div class="text">Text Here</div>
    <div class="icon">Image Here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked exactly as I expected. But I did not even have to do the flex-grow. Just making the display property of the parent flex fixed my problem. Thank you for the answer. I'll read up more on flex.